# Does a sum require 2+ numbers, such as $sum(a, b, ...)$? Does $sum(n)$ imply $n + 0$?

Tags: summation, definition, pattern-recognition

This came up when someone else asked "How many sums of positive integers result in $n$"? And they gave the example:

```
5 can be written as:
5
4+1
3+2
3+1+1
2+2+1
2+1+1+1
1+1+1+1+1
```

But, this brings up an interesting question that would fundamentally change pattern recognition for their question. The first entry of their list is 5, which implies they're intending $sum(5)$ to be valid.

But... does this actually imply $sum(5,0)$?

If so, should the first item in the list be disregarded since 0 is not a positive integer?

Comment: I think this is standard terminology, but you're missing the point.  He's *telling* you what counts as a sum in the problem at hand.

Comment: As @saulspatz says, the context removes the ambiguity. Sums of the elements of one-element sets are common. In fact, there are very good reasons for declaring that the sum of the empty set of numbers is $0$ (and the product of the empty set of numbers is $1$).

Comment: @saulspatz Fair, but I was wanting to clarify the parameters of the problem. And sorry, which is the standard terminology? Are you saying the sum of a single number is valid?

Comment: @MrMusAddict Not only that; the sum of *no* numbers is valid and is conventionally equal to $0$.

Comment: @MrMusAddict Yes, the sum of a number is valid.  You can think of it as the sum of a set of numbers.  And as Patrick Stevens points out, the sum of the empty set is zero.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Side question then; programming has taught me that there's a difference between null and 0. Null being "no data" and 0 being a value. I realize this is not programming, but I have to ask; In the case of summing nothing (sum(null)), would the result be more akin to null, or 0?

Comment: @MrMusAddict: I would say that the sum of no numbers is genuinely $0$, but the average of no numbers is more null-like...

Comment: FWIW, the Python expression `sum([])` returns 0.

Comment: @MrMusAddict Your question about `sum(null)` is not well-formed. A properly-implemented `sum` takes a single list as its argument, though that list may be empty. In a language which allows multiple dispatch of functions, and which has lists, we might be allowed to use a shorthand `sum(1, 2, 3)` to convert the $3$-ary function `sum` into its $1$-ary `sum([1,2,3])`.

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of elements $[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$, we define the *sum* of this list to be $a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n$.

This definition is fine when $n=1$: then given a list $[a_1]$, we define its *sum* to be $a_1$.

When $n=0$, we conventionally take the sum of the empty list $[]$ to be $0$. This allows us to maintain the property that $$\mathrm{sum}(l_1) + \mathrm{sum}(l_2) = \mathrm{sum}(l_1 \oplus l_2)$$
where $\oplus$ is my ad-hoc notation for the concatenation operation: $$[a_1, \dots, a_n] \oplus [b_1, \dots, b_m] := [a_1, \dots, a_n, b_1, \dots, b_m]$$